# What is the carriage return character in an AS/400 db?

Tags: ibm-midrange, carriage-return

I have a client running an AS/400. I have to ftp a flat file over to them. They tell me their return charaters are RN. I don't recognize this, could not find anything on it, and their tech guy is Nick Burns so he refuses to give me any dirtection. Is there a standard return code for AS/400?

I should have mentioned that I have a c# .NET 2.0 console application.

Comment: lol @ Nick Burns. "Moooove!", "Oh, by the way... You're welcome!" But on a more serious note... this sounds more like a ServerFault question. Migrate?

Comment: Can't you ftp (using binary mode) an example of a 'correct' file from the AS/400 to your unix system, run od -x on that file, and decode the hex to learn how the lines should end?

Comment: @Paul: Why the OS/400 hate?  If he were asking about Windows, Max, or Linux, no one would even think of moving it to serverfault.  RPG and CL programmers are programmers too, you know :)

Comment: Are you talking about newlines to delimit records, or do you mean newlines that are actually part of data (i.e. embedded in a single field)?

Comment: @BlueRaja: No hate. Before the mention of a console app this sounded purely like an OS-specific question that seemed a better fit for ServerFault.

Answer (score 11):

The AS/400 uses [EBCDIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) as a character set, rather than either the DOS or Unix ASCII character set.  In Unix, text file lines typically end with ASCII `'\n'` and in DOS lines typically end with ASCII `'\r\n'`.

When you FTP, if you use the `EBCDIC` transfer type, rather than `bin` or `ASCII`; ftp is supposed to translate these characters for you.

EBCDIC carriage-return is 0x0D, just like ASCII.
EBCDIC line-feed is 0x25, unlike ASCII 0x0A.

AS/400 EBCDIC new-line has 0x15 - `NEL` (NExt Line").

For more information on end-of-line termination, see [this Wikipedia article.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)

Comment: Despite the Wikipedia article, I am not convinced that NEL is a commonly used AS/400 newline character.  We've always used CR and LF characters on the AS/400 when communicating with other machines.

Comment: I should add that we've also never stored newlines *within* a field, except specifically for data that is eventually destined for an outside machine, not for use on the AS/400 itself.  And of course, in those situations we would use LF or CRLF, not NEL.

Comment: Is the LF you use 0x25 or 0x0A?

Comment: If the rest of the data is EBCDIC and I'm relying on a separate translation step (as you say, FTP *should* do this), I leave it as 0x25.  However, I do sometimes prepare ASCII data on the AS/400, in which case it will be 0x0A.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps they mean \r\n?

Answer (score 0):

\r\n

CRLF

Carridge return followd by a Line feed

Comment: And everyone beware of Nick Burns

Comment: but, do I just add this as a string to the end of the line?

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention you are using C#, simply use [Environment.NewLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx) and don't worry about it :)

Comment: I was doing that for my local tests, but thought it I did for the ftp file, it would send the .NET carraige return over to AS/400 and would fails since they are both diff "Environments".

Comment: There is no ".Net carriage return" - .Net uses the carriage return for whatever system you're running.  As for FTP: If you are using the correct transfer type (EBCDIC, as mentioned by Heath above), it will translate the return-characters for you between different systems.