# AS400 iSeries DB2: break lines at new line character for SQL output for JSON_OBJECT

Tags: sql, json, db2, ibm-midrange

I am writing the below mentioned query in the interactive session of sql in AS/400 (STRSQL)

```
SELECT 
CAST(
json_object ('Product_id' value PROID,'Product_name' value PRONAME)as 
VARCHAR(100))
from Product
```

The output that I am getting looks something like this

```
{"Product_id":"PRD001","Product_name":"Dairy"}
```

The output for JSON object is a CLOB data, so I have typecasted it to VARCHAR.
If I am not wrong, there are new line characters (\n) and tabs (\t) in the output, but they are not getting displayed. I need the output with the new line characters and tabs.

The output should be something like:

```
{
 "Product_id":"PRD001",
 "Product_name":"Dairy"
}
```

Comment: Why do you believe that "there are new line characters and tabs" in the output? did you look at it in debug? The [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/db2/rbafzscajsonobject.htm) for `json_object` does not mention newlines or tabs, but does indicate that the output will look like what you are getting. Maybe you need to write a pretty print routine to get what you want.

Comment: Don't worry about the formating.  White space is ignored in JSON and actually it saves a few electrons.  My shop doesn't have the JSON_OBJECT function installed yet....

Answer (score 1):

Carriage return/new line characters differ in the AS400 as compared to DOS/Linux.

EBCDIC carriage-return is 0x0D, just like ASCII.
EBCDIC line-feed is 0x25, unlike ASCII 0x0A.

Source: [What is the carriage return character in an AS/400 db?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803622/what-is-the-carriage-return-character-in-an-as-400-db)

Comment: Can you tell me how to convert the new line characters of CLOB data to one that is compatible with AS400?

Comment: I would suggest using `REPLACE` https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_73/db2/rbafzscareplace.htm or mabye `TRANSLATE` https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_73/db2/rbafzscatrans.htm